# Sitecore Intranet Portal How to Delete 'User Profile' upon deleting the User

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-intranet-portal

If a user **Asdf** is deleted from Sitecore (`Security -> User Manager`), its profile (Item) remains in the content tree (`/sitecore/content/Intranet/User Profiles`).

I would like to delete the User Profile automatically if the user is deleted. Is there any event handler for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add new handler to `user:deleted` event:

```xml
<event name="user:deleted">
    <handler 
        type="My.Assembly.Namespace.DeleteUserHandler, My.Assembly" 
        method="OnUserDeleted" />
</event>
```

You can extract user name from the args like that:

```cs
public class DeleteUserHandler
{
    public void OnUserDeleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        string userName = Event.ExtractParameter<string>(args, 0);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you just need to find and delete proper profile item.